# Cpanel image not displaying

Tags: cpanel

I have removed the old image in the **cpanel** and added a new image in to it.But still displaying the old image. I have checked the production version of the **cpanel** and in that folder it has the latest image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empty trash in cpanel File Manager